# Unable to view printk output

Tags: linux, kernel

I have been trying to debug my kernel code with printk statements. But the messages does not show up on the console. cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk gives 7 4 1 7.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

use the command:

```
dmesg -E
```

-E : enable printing messages to console

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and look for any `kern.*` rules. That should tell you where the kernel levels are printing out to. You can also specify your own location like:

```
kern.debug                  /var/log/kernDebug.log
```

for kernel messages at the debug level.